# Texture behaves weird on a plane

Tags: texturing

I'm in a making of a video game and I have an alpha texture on a plane. The plane is subdivided once (without smoothing). However, when I deform the plane symmetrically, the texture doesn't deform symmetrically even though the plane is symmetrically deformed. By any means of logic this appears very strange to me since the UVs are symmetrical with the image as well -

Flat -

[image]

Deforemed -

[image]

And as I move the bottom left and top right vertices on the Z axis, the texture remains still as if the plane is not deformed

[image]

What seems to be casing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Quad is in reality 2 triangles and the behavior you observed is caused by this. Triangulate your mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and rotate the created edges like you want with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > Rotate Edge CW / CCW.

Comment: This only happens to non planar faces,  AFAIK